# Import autofill data from a file into Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, autofill

I have a CSV file of users (with email and name). Google Chrome stores its autofill data and you can add them manually here: chrome://settings/addresses

Is it possible to import the data automatically from the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The settings UI uses an internal API `chrome.autofillPrivate.saveAddress` ([source](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/resources/settings/autofill_page/autofill_section.js?l=68&rcl=31944011fe8ab26755dce300b1ec86c311860609)).

1. go to `chrome://settings/addresses`
2. open devtools console
3. paste and run the code below that adds an input button in the top right corner where you can select your CSV file:
   [image]

```js
for (const el of document.querySelectorAll('body > input'))
  el.remove();
Object.assign(document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('input')), {
  type: 'file',
  style: 'position:absolute; top:2ex; right:0; z-index:999',
  onchange(e) {
    if (!this.files[0])
      return;
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsText(this.files[0], 'UTF-8');
    fr.onload = () => {

      for (const line of fr.result.split(/\r?\n/)) {
        const [name, email] = line.split(',');
        chrome.autofillPrivate.saveAddress({
          emailAddresses: [email],
          fullNames: [name],
        });
      }

    };
    fr.onerror = console.error;
  },
});
```

- To process quoted and multi-line fields in CSV you should modify this primitive code, there are many examples of parsing CSV in JavaScript properly.
- You can save the code in [devtools snippets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets) to reuse it later.
- You can't use this private API in an extension.
- Supported fields and their types are listed in [autofill_private.js](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/closure_compiler/externs/autofill_private.js)