# Is it possible to set autofill form data via chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am looking to build a chrome extension wherein I the extension can set the chrome autofill for a person (i.e. save addresses and other information like basic form data). I can then go to a few websites, fill a few forms.

The extension can then set the data for another person and the cycle repeats.

Since the forms can contain dynamic fields, I want this data set in the autofill so chrome can take care of most of the part and I can rectify any problems before submitting the form.

I haven't found a direct chrome extension API to do this. Is this possible to be done?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I went through this: [Import autofill data from a file into Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56967729/import-autofill-data-from-a-file-into-chrome) but is there any way to do it through the extension?

Comment: What's wrong with fill those field directly? How can chrome autofill if you don't even know what field to fill yourself?

Comment: Chrome autofill is smart enough to detect the type of fields and their variations present on a page (Like Name, First Name, Last Name) etc. along with international language support. Detecting the field types on multiple webpages is a challenging task. If it was 3-4 forms I would have coded the logic within the extension itself :)

Comment: From my experience chrome usually messup on new site :/ but interesting idea nonetheless :)